# strange type conversion

Tags: types

I just can not figure out the following code.

```
int d = 5;
float f = 3.8f;
int ret = d*f;
```

The ret is 18, not 19 as I expected. Why?

Comment: Use one of the ceil, floor or round operations; typecasting to an integer results in truncation of the floating point number (in most of the computer languages).

Comment: It is good form to state what programming language you are using instead of leaving people guessing.

Comment: Oh, come on, Pascal, it's clearly C... or C++ ... or Java ... or C# ... or something. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first is that floating point values are not decimals, so `3.8f` is really more like `3.79999999999999999999923` or something like that. The second is that when converting to an int, the system will always truncate the decimal value, rather than rounding.

So if you could peer into the processor, you'd see it doing

```
3.79999999999999999999923 * 5 = 18.999999999999999999615
```

Then you remove the non-integer portion:

```
18
```

Answer (score 3):

You're running into IEEE 754 limitations. `f` is not *exactly* `3.8`, it's just ever the slightest bit less.

Answer (score 1):

When multiplying integers and floating point numbers together, if you don't explicitly cast one to another, you are relying on the implicit conversion rules of the language you are using to do the rounding for you.  Some languages will truncate the decimal whereas some languages round the decimal value in order to make an int.  In the case of multiplying two numeric types together, if you don't know what to expect, it's always better to explicitly cast and round so you know exactly what you are getting.